# Can you use for loop decrements with a condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, for-loop

Hard to title what I mean. Let's say this activates on resize.

```
  for ( i = 10; i > 1; i--) { 
    console.log(i);
    if(inner>outer) {
      console.log('this' + i);
      inn.css('font-size', i+'0%')
    }
  }
```

and when if condition is met with, it uses the loop number gained to decrease it's font-size, but it uses the last loop number which is 2 which gets 20%.

Is there a way to if inner>outer use the first decrement 10, if inner is still bigger use 9, if still bigger 8 etc ?

Comment: Even with the description it's hard to understand what you're trying to do. I'd suggest giving us information about what you want to achieve instead of explaining your attempted solution.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: What is `inner` and `outer`? And wheres the whole code in?

Comment: Is it your problem again to resize the font-size relative with the inner height when it is less than the outer div height? I assume, perhaps the slide question.

Comment: I think i got it...but, it will not work like you want it... loop is 'too fast', simple... so, on resize, if certain condition is meet, start loop, with different i vars...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Last paragraph, On resize I want to decrement font-size until it fits. font-size:90%;font-size:80%;font-size:70%;font-size:60%; etc
Until if ( inner>outer) condition is met.

Comment: By 'fit' you mean no line breaks, I assume?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I tried asking it simply. the fitting is unimportant the question right now. When I apply var i to the font-size: i+'%' and when var i loops from 10 to 2 it , it uses the last number for the css value so we are getting font-size 20%. I want it to use the first looped var i = 10 or 9 , 8 etc ... so font-size would loop through all of numbers - - ofcourse I want the number to stop somewhere if above mentioned if condition is met.

Comment: Okay, updated my answer with something more specific now that it's more clear what you were looking for.

Comment: What condition? `inner > outer` I presume, but what exactly are we checking is `>` than the other? You're drip feeding us information here.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I was trying to simplify alas: https://codepen.io/rKaiser/pen/rpBKqJ?editors=1011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third portion of the `for()` statement needs to be an expression, and it needs to eventually cause your `for` condition to fail or you're going to be in an infinite loop, but otherwise certainly CAN be more complex than a simple increment or decrement operation. For instance, you could use a function call there.

That said, this will produce code that's very hard to read for most people, because it's remarkably uncommon to use anything there but a basic incrementer. You should consider a different form of loop if that's the behavior you want; you may be able to get the result you want in a more idiomatic / legible way.

But if you want to use a `for` loop, it might look like this:

```
for (var i=100; inner<=outer; i-=10) {
  inn.css('font-size', i+'%');
  // Some call here that updates 'inner' with the new size; unclear where you got that from originally
}
```

Most people would probably use a `while` loop for this, but a `for` loop can work as long as the value of `inner` or `outer` is changed by the block statement so that the loop will eventually exit.

Comment: See this https://codepen.io/rKaiser/pen/rpBKqJ?editors=1011 , are we on the same page, your answer doesnt seem to work.

Comment: https://codepen.io/smmccrohan/pen/WdbZrW/ - shrink the window horizontally to see the text scale. The overflow detection isn't perfect, so you'll want to play with that a bit, but it demonstrates the idea.